# Closed 4-manifolds with uncountably many differentiable structures

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, smooth-manifolds, examples, 4-manifolds, smooth-structures

I know that $\mathbb{R}^4$ admits uncountably many differentiable structures and I was wandering what happen if we consider closed 4-manifolds. Are there any closed 4-manifolds with uncountably many differentiable structures?

Comment: No, there are only countably-many diffeomorphism types of compact 4-manifolds, since each one has a finite PL-compatible triangulation, and that determines the diffeomorphism type uniquely.  Moreover, there's an outstanding conjecture in 4-manifold theory: every compact smoothable 4-manifold admits countably-infinite distinct smooth structures.

Comment: I suppose this conjecture is due to Fintushel-Stern, but is there actually some reference for its first occurence?

Comment: The first occurrence of it I remember was at Ron Stern's talk at the last Topology Festival.  I think that was at Cornell in the summer of 2012.  Fintushel and Stern would likely know of any earlier occurrence.